# Vue JS router query passing and bind to the axios

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios, vue-router

My use case is something like this.

1. User come to **questionPapersTable.vue** and choose a paper name and hit on a **Start exam** button

[image]

2. then the user is route to the **startExam.vue component** from there I want to pass that id parameter value to the axios as a parameter and want to display that id parameter in this **StartExam.vue** component.
   I tried

> ID comes is : {{$route.query.id}}

But this isn't display anything and even not give an error in console.
How do I achive this. This is my code.

**questionPapersTable.vue**

```
<template lang="html">
  <div class="">
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Paper Name</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>

      <tr v-for="n in 10">
        <td>Demo</td>
        <th><button @click="goStart(12)">Start exam</button></th>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods:{
    goStart(paperId){
      console.log("GO TO START EXAM!");
      this.$router.push({
        path:'/startExam',
        params:{
          id:paperId
        }

    });
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**startExam.vue**

```
<template lang="html">
  <div class="">
  <h1>Start Exam</h1>
  ID comes is : {{$route.query.id}}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
  created(){
    axios.get('http://localhost/laravel_back/public/api/papers/' +id)
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="css">
</style>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

params are ignored if a path is provided:

```
router.push({ name: 'startExamName', params: { docId }}) // -> /startExam/123
router.push({ path: `/startExam/${docId}` }) // -> /startExam/123

// This will NOT work
router.push({ path: '/startExam', params: { docId }}) // -> /startExam
```

Within in the javascript code if you want to access the id,

```
this.$route.params.id
```

https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/navigation.html

Comment: i fixed it but I didn't get output to ID comes is : {{$route.query.id}}

Comment: How is your url structured now? If you are using params, it has to be `{{$route.params.id}}`

Comment: Now it's coming. =) I do a silly mistake I put {{$route.params.id}} instead of {{$route.query.id}}. But still I can't call that in created() hook. I tied to console log inside created lifecycle hook console.log("Inside created",$route.params.id); but it says $route is not defined

Comment: You should use `this.$route.params.id`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works! I highly appreciate your support. =)